# Vue 2 props on child component undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I'm trying to pass a prop down to a child component as follows.

```
<Project :grossMarginPerResource="grossMarginPerResource" :threshold="threshold" :orderBy="orderBy" @refetch="refetch" v-if="group_by == 'Project'"></Project>
```

The child component accepts this prop

```
props: ['grossMarginPerResource', 'orderBy', 'show_costs','threshold'],
```

Whenever I try to access this prop, either by console logging it, it prints out as undefined,

Logging it in the parent component shows the following:

```
{ "green": "1000", "yellow": "400", "red": "400" }
```

but if I do in the child component:

```
console.log(this.threshold)
```

it prints out undefined

Comment: where do you do console log in child and how `threshold` is defined in parent?

Comment: Please create a *runnable* [mcve] (either using a SO snippet or, if you prefer, codesandbox.io or similar). What you posted is not enough to repro the bug.

Comment: in which event are you doing console.log() ? It could be because data is not yet available when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, To find the root cause I just created this code snippet and it is working fine as per the code you mentioned above. Can you please have a look and confirm at which place you are facing issue as `console.log` will return the `threshold` data in all the life cycle hooks.

Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('Project', {
  props: ['threshold'],
  template: '<pre>{{ threshold }}</pre>',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.threshold)
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        threshold: { "green": "1000", "yellow": "400", "red": "400" }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Project :threshold="threshold"></Project>
</div>
```